# Add a column based on multiple values in a different column

Tags: r

I have bunch od columns in a data frame, two of which are like this

```
col1 | col2
-----| -------------
 2   | M
 3   | B
 1   | m
 5   | K
 3   | k
```

What I want is to create a new column that would contain:

value from col1 * 10^3 if value in col2 is k or K,
           col1 * 10^6 if the value in col2 is M or m,
           col1 * 10^9 if the value in col2 is B,
           and 0 if it is anything else.

I know how to do ifelse when there is binary condition, but I don't know how to do it with multiple conditions like this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a named vector and match that with your "col2" column to create your multiplier. All values other than M, m, K, k, B, or b would result in `NA`, so if you want "0", you just subset for `NA` from your new column and replace it with 0 manually.

```
Mults <- c(M = 10^6, m = 10^6, K = 10^3, k = 10^3, B = 10^9, b = 10^9)
Mults[mydf$col2]
#     M     B     m     K     k  <NA> 
# 1e+06 1e+09 1e+06 1e+03 1e+03    NA 
mydf$col3 <- mydf$col1 * Mults[mydf$col2]
mydf$col3[is.na(mydf$col3)] <- 0
mydf
#   col1 col2  col3
# 1    2    M 2e+06
# 2    3    B 3e+09
# 3    1    m 1e+06
# 4    5    K 5e+03
# 5    3    k 3e+03
# 6    3    x 0e+00
```

---

Here's the "mydf" that I used (with an extra row):

```
mydf <- structure(list(col1 = c(2, 3, 1, 5, 3, 3), col2 = c("M", "B", 
    "m", "K", "k", "x"), col3 = c(2e+06, 3e+09, 1e+06, 5000, 3000, 0)), 
    .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
    class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4):

`switch` could be used:

```
f <- function(multi, test)
  multi * switch(tolower(test),
         "m" = 10^6,
         "k" = 10^3,
         "b" = 10^9,
         0
  )
within(df, col3 <- mapply(f, col1, col2, SIMPLIFY=TRUE))
#   col1 col2  col3
# 1    2    M 2e+06
# 2    3    B 3e+09
# 3    1    m 1e+06
# 4    5    K 5e+03
# 5    3    k 3e+03
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not elegant at all, but you can do it like this. The problem is it can get tiresome if you have many more possible cases.

```
DB <- data.frame(col1=c(2,3,1,5,3), col2=c("M","B","m","K","k"))
DB$col3 <- NA
DB$col3 <- ifelse(DB$col2=="K" | DB$col2=="k", DB$col1 * (10^3), DB$col3)
DB$col3 <- ifelse(DB$col2=="M" | DB$col2=="m", DB$col1 * (10^6), DB$col3)
DB$col3 <- ifelse(DB$col2=="B", DB$col1 * (10^9), DB$col3)
DB$col3 <- ifelse(is.na(DB$col2)==TRUE, 0, DB$col3)
```

or you could also do this

```
DB <- data.frame(col1=c(2,3,1,5,3), col2=c("M","B","m","K","k"))
DB2 <- data.frame(col2=c("M","B","m","K","k"), tmp=c(10^6,10^9,10^6,10^3, 10^3))
DB<- merge(DB, DB2, by="col2")
DB$col3 <- DB$col1 * DB$tmp
DB$tmp <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using `mapply` and `mget`.

```
x <- with(mydf, list(K=col1*10^3, M=col1*10^6, B=col1*10^9, col2=toupper(col2)))
mydf$col3 <- 
do.call(mapply, c(function(K,M,B,col2) unlist(mget(col2, ifnotfound=0)), x))
#   col1 col2  col3
# 1    2    M 2e+06
# 2    3    B 3e+09
# 3    1    m 1e+06
# 4    5    K 5e+03
# 5    3    k 3e+03
# 6    3    x 0e+00
```